# Installing W2K8 R2 on a Dell Poweredge 2850

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, dell-poweredge

I'm a server novice and have been given a Dell 2850 (PERC 4e/Di). It has 3 blank HDs that I think are configured as RAID 5.  I am trying to install W2K8 R2 SP1 on it. It doesn't have a DVD reader so I created an install USB. This works fine until it's time to copy files to the HD. It can't see a HD. There is an option to browse for drivers at this stage. Any idea what drivers I need and where to download them?

I downloaded this driver RAID_DRVR_WIN_R227150.EXE but this failed with invalid signature. Thanks to dyasny for the link to LSI-LOGIC_MULTI-DEVICE_A00_R227150.exe.

Comment: does the server have a DRAC?

Comment: no don't have a DRAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails?DriverId=9K3D3&FileId=2731109791&DeviceId=HK753&DriverName=LSI%20Logic%20PERC%204e%2FDC%2C%20Perc%204e%2FDi%2C%20PERC%204e%2FSi%2C%20v.6.53.0.64%2C%20A00 is the package you need- download, unpack, and put on a cd/floppy/usb stick, and during windows setup, point to these files

The file is called

> LSI-LOGIC_MULTI-DEVICE_A00_R227150.exe

BTW, with a DRAC, you can attach a DVD ISO image remotely and install from it, but that's irrelevant to the issue at hand

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working - setup has now copied the files!

Comment: dyasny are 100% right. PUt this on an USB, and tell the server to collect it. It will uses atleast 30 seconds or so to find the disks but it works :).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get drivers from Dell directly.  If it's not supported, you'll have to dig around and try and find similar drivers from elsewhere.

Didn't they do something in R2 with SCSI drivers?

Have a [Google around](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Dell%202850%20PERC%204e/Di%20windows%202008), I think it's a [known thing](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19278161.aspx)